# How to simplify Async functionality in Flutter Bloc (Cubit) State Management?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I'm exploring flutter_bloc **Cubit** state management, having previously used Riverpod 2.0,
I want to implement async functionality using the flutter_bloc (Cubit) state management approach, Coming from a **Riverpod 2.0** background, I find that Cubit are similar to Riverpod **Notifier** class. However, I couldn't find an equivalent to **AsyncNotifier** class with built in support for async states such as loading, data, error in Cubit.

It appears that in **Cubit** to perform async functionality, I need to create a state class with user-defined async states such as loading, data, error, which could lead to a lot of boilerplate code, especially for numerous async operations. Is there a simpler way to achieve this in cubit, or do I need to create a separate state class for each async functionality?

Example - Riverpod async functionality with AsyncNotifier which takes cares of async state such as loading, data, and error.

```
 class AsyncTodosNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<List<Todo>> {

 @override
  Future<List<Todo>> build() async {
    // Load initial todo list from the remote repository
    return _fetchTodo();
  }

  Future<void> addTodo(Todo todo) async {
    // Set the state to loading
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    // Add the new todo and reload the todo list from the remote repository
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      await http.post('api/todos', todo.toJson());
      return _fetchTodo();
    });
  }
}
```

Example - Cubit Async functionality with custom state class with async state such as loading, success, failure

```
class ComplexListCubit extends Cubit<ComplexListState> {
Future<void> fetchList() async {
    try {
      emit(ComplexListState.loading());
      final items = await repository.fetchItems();
      emit(ComplexListState.success(items));
    } on Exception {
      emit(const ComplexListState.failure());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, there are no analogies to AsyncNotifier from the box in the flutter_bloc. So, if you have states from ComplexListState, in widget it will looks like:

```
    ..
BlocBuilder<ComplexListCubit, ComplexListState>(
          builder: (context, listState) => switch (listState) {
              ComplexListState.loading() => ProgressLoader(),
              ComplexListState.success() => BodyView(),
              ComplexListState.failure() => ErrorWidget(),       
          },
        ),
    ...
```

but if you want to use something like AsyncNotifier, you could used https://pub.dev/packages/freezed as one of the possible options.